# upload an image using AFNetworking to the server by node.js failed

Tags: ios, node.js, express

I am learning AFNetworking(v3.0) these days, I try to use it to upload an image to my server writen by node.js + express. I found every time I tried to call upload method in ***.m I got error message, said the "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"(part of error message)", is that a problem maybe my request is wrong? Or the sever side's problem? I am new to node.js and express. What I guess is type problem? maybe but I don't know. If you know~ please reply me ~ thanks!

iOS Side:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"enctype": @"multipart/form-data"};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://localhost:8080/images" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"pic" fileName:@"pic.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"上传成功");
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Server Side:

```
router.route('/images').post(multiparty(), function(req, res) {
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function(err, data) {
    var imageName = req.files.image.name;

    if (!imageName) {
        console.log("there was an error");
        res.json({message:"error", code:500});
    } else {
        var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
            res.json({message: 'successfully upload image!', code:200});
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iOS code is using `pic` as the field name, not `image` like you are referencing on the server side. One or the other would need to be changed.